# Functional tests for common PHP5 extensions

Tags: php, testing, webserver, functional-testing

I'm a python programmer, but I need to test if everything works fine on a webserver after PHP upgrade.

I'm not very familiar with PHP, and I'm looking for some functional tests (common operations which make use of the PHP extensions). I've done quite a bit of searching, but everything I found is related to some bigger frameworks. I just need some simple, but preferably ready scripts that can work as functional tests :)

Extensions load properly, and get_loaded_extensions() method returns a clear list:

```
Core date ereg libxml openssl pcre sqlite3 zlib bz2 ctype dom
fileinfo  filter hash iconv intl json mbstring SPL session standard PDO     
mysqlnd pdo_sqlite Phar posix pspell Reflection pdo_mysql shmop 
SimpleXML soap sockets mysqli tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter zip
apache2handler bcmath calendar curl dba exif ftp gd gettext imagick imap
ldap mailparse mcrypt ming mysql pdo_pgsql pgsql sysvsem sysvshm xmlrpc
xsl dbase
```

So my question is: does anyone know about a repo or other source that would have such tests, or am I forced to do everything from scratch? :)

Answer (score 0):

Since my question is probably not the brightest one, I'll answer it with what I've done:

a php script for each extension, which contains examples from php.net documentation (for example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-cntrl.php).

Each script should return a set output; files are sent to the server by a python script. Then, http requests are sent to each script, and response is evaluated.

extension list and .htaccess behavior is also evaluated based on the output.

Not the brightest answer to a dim-wutted question, but there it is :) close enough.